# find and update in mongodb for multilevel nested query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, monk

My document structure is as follows

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55ae24016fb73f6ac7c2d640"
    },
    "Name": "some name",
    "District": "some district",
    "Stories": [
        {
            "userId": "105304831528398207103",
            "story": "some story",
            "Likes": ["user id 1" ..... ],
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "55c055af1875b0002572cf94"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when a user likes a story, i want to add his user id to the array **Likes**

I tried the following code

```
router.post("/NewStoryLike", function (req, res) {
    var mongo = require('mongodb');
    var db = require('monk');
    var ObjectID = mongo.ObjectID;
    req.db.get('clnTemple').findAndModify({
        query: { "_id": ObjectID(req.body.postId) ,"Stories._id": ObjectID(req.body.storyId) },
        update: { $addToSet: { Likes: req.body.userId } },
        upsert: true
    });
    res.send("Like Added");
});
```

Its not throwing any errors but its not adding user id to likes array, instead it is adding an Likes in top level, i.e its adding to post level

What change should be made?

Comment: Your query refers to "Likes", but your structure refers to "likes".

Comment: Read the documentation. [Positional `$` update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). It is **very** clear.

Comment: @AssafHershko thanks, corrected the typo

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks will check it out

Comment: Now its adding after i changed the code that is in updated question, but likes is getting added outside the stories

Comment: Also, there is no reason to use "findAndModify" if all you want to do is update the record. Just use "update".

Comment: Are you using "{ $addToSet: { 'Stories.$.likes': req.body.userId }" now?

Comment: @AssafHershko thanks for mentioning! it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using nested arrays is a bad idea for design. This is because of the limitations of what you can do with array updates in MongoDB. As stated in the documentation for the [positional `$` update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays) operator:

> **Nested Arrays**
>
> The positional $ operator **cannot** be used for queries which traverse **more than one array**, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a **single value**

It is perfectly fine however to just `$push|$addToSet` where the only array you are actually matching **is** the outer array and therefore the "first" array element matched. As long as you have your naming correct:

```
req.db.get('clnTemple').findAndModify({
    { 
        "_id": req.body.postId ,
        "Stories._id": ObjectID(req.body.storyId),
    },
    { "$addToSet": { "Stories.$.Likes": req.body.userId } },
    { "new": true },
    function(err,doc) {
       // updted doc in here
    }
);
```

Aside from that you should not really be using nested arrays, this will work just fine, since it is only appending to the "inner" array of the matched "outer" array.

As a personal preference, I model "Likes" much more differently and much more reliably. But that is another question.

Comment: so what is a better way to store likes? 
Should it be in a different collection?

Comment: @vignesh If you have additional questions then [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which is basically the model here on this site, and as a Q&A resource, then "one question" to "one ( well one best ) answer" is what everyone wants to see. You can also "learn" from the fact that my own account postings link back to my profile with previous answers already given here ( just like everyone else ), and when I say "I do it differently", it means I have likely already shown someone else in another answer, exactly the process I mean.

Comment: @vignesh Something wrong here that you do not understand? You cannot seriously expect people to answer additional questions you ask to your original question. Ask another question. Just accepting another question is a basic benefit to yourself as well as others.

Comment: yup Kira i hear you. Will post a seperate question on codereview stackexchange as it is not allowed to be posted on SO

Comment: @vignesh No. This would be off-topic on Codereview.SE as the code is not working.

Comment: @EthanBierlein yeah, not this code, i was about to ask blakes about how to store likes in the model